# Comparing mean squared errors for estimators

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, means, mean-square-error

Let random sample $(X_{1},...X_{n})$ is taken from a population with mean $\mu $ and variance $\sigma ^{2}$. Compare suggesting estimators for $\mu $ according to mean squared error.

Suggesting estimators are , $T_{1}=\frac{3X_{1}-X_{2}-X_{3}+4X_{n}}{5}$ and $T_{2}=\frac{X_{1}}{2}-\frac{X_{2}}{3}+\frac{X_{n}}{6}$

**Here is my solution :** $E(X)=\mu $ and  $var(X)=\sigma ^{2}$

$E(T_{1})=E(\frac{3X_{1}-X_{2}-X_{3}+4X_{n}}{5})=\frac{5\mu }{5}=\mu $ and $var(T_{1})=var(\frac{3X_{1}-X_{2}-X_{3}+4X_{n}}{5})=\frac{27}{25}\sigma ^{2}$

$MSE(T_{1};\mu )=Var(T_{1})+(E(T_{1})-\mu ))^{2}=\frac{27}{25}\sigma ^{2}$

$E(T_{2})=E(\frac{X_{1}}{2}-\frac{X_{2}}{3}+\frac{X_{n}}{6})=\frac{1}{3}\mu $ and $var(T_{2})=var(\frac{X_{1}}{2}-\frac{X_{2}}{3}+\frac{X_{n}}{6})=\frac{7}{18}\sigma ^{2}$

$MSE(T_{2};\mu )=Var(T_{2})+(E(T_{2})-\mu ))^{2}=\frac{7}{18}\sigma ^{2}+\frac{4}{9}\mu ^{2}$

But how can I compare these two mean squared error. I do not know the value of $\mu ^{2}$

$MSE(T_{1};\mu )<MSE(T_{2};\mu )$ or $MSE(T_{2};\mu )<MSE(T_{1};\mu )$?

Comment: Nice question. If you don't get satisfactory answers here you might want to ask the moderators to move it to stats.stackexchange.com. I'm sure people there are able to help you.

Comment: I think $T_2$ should be $X_1/2 \color{red}{+} X_2/3 +X_n/6$. If not, it's obvious that $T_2$ is a biased estimator and can't be used.

Answer (score 3):

The method of evaluating two estimators conparing their MSE is applied if both are biased, or in case of both unbiased comparing their variances.

In your case you have $T_1$ unbiased and $T_2$ biased thus $T_1$ is preferred

---

EDIT

As I told before, **the usual procedure is to prefer the unbiased estimator Vs the biased one**, but obviously different decisions can be taken w.r.t. the various values of $\mu$. For example if $\mu=0$ $T_2$ is preferred.

Setting $\sigma^2=1$ without loss of generality, observe the following drawing

[image]

As you can see $T_2$ is preferred to $T_1$ when the "squared true mean" $\mu^2$ is less than 1.56.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable interpretation of what the writer of the question intended. If we only looked at variance and not at bias, then I could define $T_3 = 0$ regardless of the data and it would "win".

Comment: But we don't compare for unbiased or biased criteria we just compare sizes @tommik

Comment: @softglance: see my edits.

Comment: as you told , different decisions can be taken w.r.t the various values of $\mu $ so this question is not great . Which should I decide , really confused.

Comment: @softglance : consider also the possibility that there is a typo in the exercise, as noted before by NN2